# mongoose divide two fields in put request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can I update a field of a document with a division of two fields? Using Node and MongoDB, I'm trying to create a rating function, and I have to make a division, but nothing seems to work. I want the new value of rating to be, the current one divided by the number of votes.

```
router.put("/:id/:rating", async (req, res) => {
    const movie_rating = parseInt(req.params.rating);
    try {
        const updatedMovie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                $inc: { noVotes: 1 },
                $inc: { rating: movie_rating },
                $divide: { rating: [rating, noVotes] },
                // rating: { $divide: [rating, noVotes] }
            },
            { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedMovie);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change few things

[Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zjkQ47wtCwv)

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "key2": {
        $add: [
          "$key2",
          1
        ]
      },
      key3: {
        "$divide": [
          {
            $add: [
              "$key2",
              1
            ]
          },
          "$key"
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true,
  "upsert": false
})
```

1. You need aggregate update as you need `divide`
2. You cannot use the updated value in the same operation
3. You cannot combine $inc, $set in aggregate update
4. Alternatively, you can use $add instead $inc
5. you can reperform the operation for the divide operation than making another update call

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand a thing of what you write there, can you please replace the keys with the variable names I used?

Comment: I suggest you to give a try once to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `$set`,
It will look like this:

```
router.put("/:id/:rating", async (req, res) => {
  const movie_rating = parseInt(req.params.rating);
  try {
    const updatedMovie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      [
        {
          $set: {
            noVotes: { $sum: ["$noVotes", 1] },
            rating: { $sum: ["$rating", movie_rating] },
            averageRating: { $divide: ["$rating", "$noVotes"] },
          },
        },
      ],
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedMovie);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```